# Duplicate columns in odata metadata

Tags: entity-framework, odata, asp.net-identity

I am trying to export Asp.Net Identity classes in the OData metadata. Now the the `IdentityUserLogin` class contains three primary keys which are not marked with `[Key]` attribute. When the metadata is generated, the key definition is missing in the output

```
<EntityType Name="IdentityUserLogin">
  <Property Name="LoginProvider" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="ProviderKey" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String"/>
</EntityType>
```

Normally, to fix this all I need to do is add the keys manully using `HasKey` method like so

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.EntitySet<IdentityUserLogin>("Logins").EntityType
  .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId });

var EDM = builder.GetEdmModel();

config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api", EDM, 
  new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

while the above generates the key definition for the entity, it also creates duplicate columns

```
<EntityType Name="IdentityUserLogin">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="LoginProvider"/>
    <PropertyRef Name="ProviderKey"/>
    <PropertyRef Name="UserId"/>
  </Key>
  <Property Name="LoginProvider" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="ProviderKey" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="LoginProvider" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="ProviderKey" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String"/>
</EntityType>
```

Am I doing something wrong here ? Note that this also happens with `IdentityUserRole` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to avoid the bug mentioned [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/217) and [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/355), if one derives the identity types - e.g. in order to have different type of keys.
Since I derive all identity types and the relevant properties are virtual, I am able to override the key properties an set the [Key] attribute. Thus I don't need to explicitly define the keys and thus can avoid the duplicate-property-bug.

```
public class UserLogin : MultitenantIdentityUserLogin<Guid, Guid>
{
    [Key]
    public override Guid TenantId
    {
        get { return base.TenantId; }
        set { base.TenantId = value; }
    }

    [Key]
    public override string LoginProvider
    {
        get { return base.LoginProvider; }
        set { base.LoginProvider = value; }
    }

    [Key]
    public override string ProviderKey
    {
        get { return base.ProviderKey; }
        set { base.ProviderKey = value; }
    }

    [Key]
    public override Guid UserId
    {
        get { return base.UserId; }
        set { base.UserId = value; }
    }
}

public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
{
    [Key]
    public override Guid UserId
    {
        get { return base.UserId; }
        set { base.UserId = value; }
    }

    [Key]
    public override Guid RoleId
    {
        get { return base.RoleId; }
        set { base.RoleId = value; }
    }    
}

public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
{
    [Key]
    public override int Id
    {
        get { return base.Id; } 
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }
}
```

Regards,
Kasimier Buchcik

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicit configure the model, so you should use `ODataModelBuilder` instead of `ODataConventinalModelBuilder`, and there won't be duplicate properties.

Comment: It works, but now I need to build my whole model with keys, relations and validations manually. It works if you need alot of control of your exported model, but for this situation it means double the work, since the metadata is already defined in the model.

Comment: Usually we don't encourage to use `ODataConventionModelBuilder` and configure the model together, but what you want to achieve is a right scenario, and this is [bug](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/217) that there exist duplicate properties, but this bug's fix is a breaking change for OData WebAPI, you can follow this bug, and pull request is appreciate :)